# pandas: Perform mulitple rolling computation efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have dataset that is index on date

```
id, date, col1, col2
1, 4, 1, 12
1, 5, 2, 13
1, 6, 6, 14
2, 4, 20, 16 
2, 5, 8, 17 
2, 6, 11, 18
...
```

and I wish to compute the rolling `mean, sum, min, max` for `col1` and `col2` grouped by `id`, with window size 2 and 3. I can do that in a loop like so

```
def multi_rolling(df, winsize, column):
 [df.groupby("id")[column].rolling(winsize).mean(),
 df.groupby("id")[column].rolling(winsize).sum(),
 df.groupby("id")[column].rolling(winsize).min(),
 df.groupby("id")[column].rolling(winsize).max(),
 df.groupby("id")[column].rolling(winsize).count()]
```

Then I just have to call the above in a loop. But this feels inefficient. Is there a way to call it on all combinations of all functions and all columns and all window size more efficiently? E.g. run them in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
new_df = df.groupby("id").rolling(2)[["col1","col2"]].agg(['mean','sum','min','max','count'])
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
      col1                                                      col2        \
      mean         sum        min         max       count       mean         
      col1  col2  col1  col2 col1  col2  col1  col2  col1 col2  col1  col2   
id                                                                           
1  0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0  1.0   NaN   NaN   
   1   1.5  12.5   3.0  25.0  1.0  12.0   2.0  13.0   2.0  2.0   1.5  12.5   
   2   4.0  13.5   8.0  27.0  2.0  13.0   6.0  14.0   2.0  2.0   4.0  13.5   
2  3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0  1.0   NaN   NaN   
   4  14.0  16.5  28.0  33.0  8.0  16.0  20.0  17.0   2.0  2.0  14.0  16.5   
   5   9.5  17.5  19.0  35.0  8.0  17.0  11.0  18.0   2.0  2.0   9.5  17.5   


       sum        min         max       count       
      col1  col2 col1  col2  col1  col2  col1 col2  
id                                                  
1  0   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0  1.0  
   1   3.0  25.0  1.0  12.0   2.0  13.0   2.0  2.0  
   2   8.0  27.0  2.0  13.0   6.0  14.0   2.0  2.0  
2  3   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0  1.0  
   4  28.0  33.0  8.0  16.0  20.0  17.0   2.0  2.0  
   5  19.0  35.0  8.0  17.0  11.0  18.0   2.0  2.0
```

Comment: so doing 2 and 3 window sizes aren't possible and have to resort to looping.

Comment: @xiaodai Yes, since `rolling`'s `window` can only handle scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Because your question is ambiguous, I'm not sure if I understand what you need the output data to look like.

But see if one liner helps:

```
df.groupby("id")[column].rolling(winsize).agg(['mean','sum','min','max','count'])
```

Because you are grouping repeatedly, it is bound to be very inefficient.